# how do i make an image button to come up on my main xml after 5 seconds?

Tags: android, timer, imagebutton

I have a fade in animation and after trying everything I just can't seem to use `Timer` or `TimerTask` correctly because my app crashes. After five seconds I want my button to show up or fade in after 5 seconds.
How do I achieve this?

**Here's my code:**

```
   ImageButton hit = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.tryButton2);
   final Animation animationFadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein);
   hit.startAnimation(animationFadeIn);
```

and handler doesnt work it just make it appear without fade

Comment: You need to add code before anyone can even help, let alone, answer

Comment: Also, when asking about app crashes, post the stack trace.

Comment: and when i used timer and timertask it crashes

Comment: Have you tried the `postRunnable` method on a Handler?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps!

```
hit.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
animationFadeIn.setStartOffset(5000);
animationFadeIn.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

     @Override
     public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        hit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     }

     @Override
     public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        // Nothing to do here
     }

     @Override
     public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        // Nothing to do here
     }
  });
hit.startAnimation(animationFadeIn);
```

**EDIT:**
Here a very fast and simple way to do enable/disable a click on the button:
you can use a boolean variable:

```
private boolean hasClicked = false
```

Now add this in your OnClickListener:

```
if(!hasClicked) {
    hasClicked = true;
    // call your animate method
}
```

Now you have to "enable" the button again. You have to this in your AnimationListener
     @Override
     public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        hasClicked = false;
     }

If it was helpful, please don't forget the upvote :)

Comment: i just used setEnabled(false);